# How to pass the salesforce Ids in URL which are case sensitive?

Tags: visualforce, url

I am facing issues in passing the values to custom fields which are same as shown below.

00Ni000000CPDRf

00Ni000000CPDRF

I am passing them as shown below:

```
PageRef.getParameters().put(System.Label.abc,xyz.abc__c);
```

But when the page is loaded its displaying only one parameter. It's overriding the other Id.

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand your question from what you have provided. Are you trying to pass the 18 character ID across in the URL with getParameters().put() - and it's not doing so? Or are you having problems storing 15 character IDs in (String?) fields in an object, or ..?

Comment: I am passing the 2 field IDs in URL to a standard page using  PageRef.getParameters().put() method. The issue here is that the map is not case sensitive. It is displaying only one out of the 2 IDs in the URL. Hope this helps.

Comment: You definitely have two different identifiers for your URL parameters (System.Label.abc) ? Do they appear in the URL bar as different IDs? String Map keys are case sensitive (see the bottom of this page http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) Maybe it would be useful to see the code that is consuming the URL parameters and putting them in the map?

Comment: Only one id is getting added to the URL parameters.I fixed it by creating a URL with these parameters in the controller.Thanks for looking into it.I will try to figure out why its not working with the PageRef.getParameters().put() method.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here if you must use an id in your querysting is to use the 18-digit case-insensitive Salesforce Id rather than the 15-digit case sensitive version. Here is a utility method for getting an 18-digit Id in apex:

```
String.valueOf((Id)(15digitId));
```

Comment: i tested it by passing 18 digit ids of both of them but it didnt work..I added it in the URL directly

Comment: Further information on 15/18 character ID fields can be found in this blog post: http://srlawr.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/outputting-salesforce-18-character-id.html If that is of any use?

Comment: I am passing the 2 field IDs in URL to a standard page using  PageRef.getParameters().put();